conditional file loading in Magma (CAS)
I'm working with a rather large repository of magma files.
Sometimes for bugfixing I run file2.m, which relies on some file1.m, sometimes file3.m which loads file2.m and file1.m using
load "file1.m";
load "file2.m";

the problem is that I want to recreate something like if __name__ == "__main__" from Python to prevent overloading of file1.m when running file3.m, as the load of file2.m would load file1.m again. The problem I run into in every approach I try is that the load statement in Magma seems to only be allowed outside of conditionals, so something like
if assigned is_main_script then
    print "Script is being loaded.";
else
    is_main_script := true;
    print "Script is being executed directly.";
    load "file1.m";
    load "file2.m";
end if;

throws an error.
Are there any other solutions, when working with many interdependent magma files in one repository?

I came up with a very rough hack, which is to
when directly executing the file

write the files that need to be loaded to a separate file toload.m

when being loaded

write empty to the file toload.m

so that outside of this conditional statement, you can place
load "toload.m";
and it will load precisely those files specified in the conditional.
For example:
if assigned is_main_script then
    filename := "to_load.m";
    Write(filename, "\n" : Overwrite := true);
else
    is_main_script := true;
    filename := "to_load.m";

    files := [
        "file1.m",
        "file2.m"
    ];
    Write(filename, "\n" : Overwrite := true);
    for file in files do
        tmp :=  "load '" cat file cat "'; \n"; 
        Write(filename, tmp);
    end for;
end if;

load "to_load.m";


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
